# How to check if a key element exists and if present update it?

Tags: mule, mule-esb

I am using mule community edition. So no Dataweave. I am consuming a rest service in my application. In the json response from this backend rest service. I need to check if a particular element exists inside muliple multiple elements of an array and wherever it exists I need to update its value.

E.g. (sample)

```
Input Request : [ { "id" : "1", "item" : "car", "make" : "Tonda" }, { "id" : "1", "item" : "car" } ]
```

using foreach to iterate array . Inside for each need to do something like below in expression component.

```
if( payload.make exists) { payload.make = "Tero"; }
```

But I do not know , how to check "if element exists"" condition. I tried below in expression component

```
if( payload.make != empty) { payload.make = "Tero"; }
```

But it did not work and gives error "Execution of the expression failed (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException)"" for each array element wherever the particular key(make) is not present

Answer (score 1):

inside foreach use the expression: `#[payload.containsKey('make')]` to check if the json key make exists or not. This will return `true` or `false`

Easy and simple!
Ref: https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/71478/how-to-check-if-a-key-element-exists-and-if-presen.html?childToView=71502#answer-71502

Answer (score 0):

Tested in a flow, if your payload is a single object and not a collection you can do MEL:

`#[(payload.?make != empty) ? "EXISTS"  : " OPS NO"`]

Just change "EXISTS" with your true condition and "OPS NO" with the false one.

According to documentation:  https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mule-expression-language-reference

Null Safety

To access properties in a null safe manner, add the .? operator before one or more objects in a chain. In the following expression, if fieldA is null, the expression evaluates to null instead of a NullPointerException.